# How to customize the suggestion html with jQuery-Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using the jQuery-Autocomplete plugin seen here: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

I'm trying to control the item being rendered as a suggestion. By default, the autocomplete-suggestion looks like the following:

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0">438</div>
```

I'd like the ability to build that item so I could do something like:

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0">
    <div class="autocomplete-suggestion-photo"></div>
    <div class="autocomplete-suggestion-title"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using beforeRender which is being called, just not taking effect, here is the snippet:

```
beforeRender: function (container) {
  console.log(container)
  xx = '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="1">TEST</div>';
  return xx;
},
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Updated code below. Idea being change container in beforeRender to have full customization of what is being rendered. This had no effect.

```
beforeRender: function (container) {
  console.log(container)
  container = '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="1">TEST</div>';
  return container;
},
```

Comment: Please use proper tags. `jquery-ui-autocomplete` is not what you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/41043437c0067e36c1a53f146f34299a660a2e5e/dist/jquery.autocomplete.js#L691), the plugin just invokes `beforeRender` and then shows the container:

```
if ($.isFunction(beforeRender)) {
  beforeRender.call(that.element, container, that.suggestions);
}

that.fixPosition();
container.show();
```

It doesn't make use of any return values. And the docs says:

> **beforeRender**: `function (container, suggestions) {}` called before displaying the suggestions. You may manipulate suggestions DOM before it is displayed.

So I think you're supposed to manipulate the container directly, something like:

```
beforeRender: function (container, suggestions) {
  container.find('.autocomplete-suggestion').each(function(i, suggestion){
   // suggestion.append(); suggestion.preppend(); suggestion.whatever()
  });
},
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer. I took your note and tried editing beforeRender to modify container, thinking that would give me full render control. However that had no effect (updated code above). any ideas on how I can customize what is being rendered? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but faced a similar problem. I wanted to display results in a div instead of the default dropdown. Thought to update the workaround in case anyone has such a requirement.

First of all, the `formatResult` method is called before the `beforeRender` method. Plus the plugin adds inline style attribute to the container that makes the position of the container to absolute.

Now coming back to the original question, as @T J mentioned in the answer, the method does not use the return value so we have to make changes to the container in the method itself. Here is what I came up with.

```
beforeRender: function (container) {
    
    var html = "";
    
    //get inner html of each of the suggestion
    container.find('.autocomplete-suggestion').each(function(i, suggestion){
        html = html + $(suggestion).html();
    });
    
    //append the html to the div where you want to display the results
    $("#auto-results").html(html);
    
    /*
    * remove the inline style from the container that makes the position absolute
    * and other styles
    */
    $(container).removeAttr("style");
    
    //empty the inner html of the container
    $(container).html("");
},
```

This way, the default container is not displayed, but all the suggestions are displayed in my own container div.

Please keep in mind that the individual suggestion style is handled by the `formatResult` method.

You can make the changes you want to the container in the same way.