# Adding image into autocomplete searchbox with devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using [devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete).  in my web page and retrieving value/data pair from database. I want to add logos aside every entry and after searching I reached to this part only. [How to customize the suggestion html with jQuery-Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258427/how-to-customize-the-suggestion-html-with-jquery-autocomplete)

Is there is any way to use this `beforeRendered` function to add images in autocomplete box?